# Auto refresh upon new mysql entry

Tags: javascript, mysql

So I have built a dashboard for the company I work for, that simply displays all mysql entries that meet certain conditions.

My question is simple, but the answer might not be.

What methods can I use (JavaScript most likely) to refresh the page when a new entry is added to the database.

The database collects information from a webform, so when a new user fills out the form, I'd love the page to refresh, thus showing the new entry.

I'm currently using JavaScript to simply refresh the url that the dashboard sits on, every 5min, but I'd love to have it only update if there is a new entry.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use AJAX to query the database every 20 seconds or so, then if a new record found, refresh the page.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I need. Would AJAX look for a count then update if the count was different?

Comment: I guess I need to learn more, I thought AJAX could not query mysql since its client side.

Comment: Your ajax script would need to communicate with a backend server-based language (such as PHP or ASP). The PHP or ASP etc would then query the database for new records and return a result. You may want to look into jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

See at the end of the answer for an advanced solution, using web sockets to notify users of changes...

### Basic Solution

At regularly intervals you can send a Ajax request to your application to check for changes. This is called short polling (in case you want to research it some more). Basically, every 30 seconds you would request some script on your application that would check for changes.

Changes can be detected either based on a last modified date, or based on a hash snapshot of a serialized object if you can't rely on last modified.

If there is a change, you could then return that through the Ajax request. If possible, you then don't also need to do a full refresh if you can send all of the changes along the same request. (Or just have the client request another page).

### Advanced Solution

The typical approach that I use is as follows...

- User connects to a webpage and opens a websocket to the server (or long polling if WS isn't supported on their browser). There are lots of libraries/servies out there such as Pusher.js or Socket.io (if you want to run it yourself) for handling this.
- The user will "connect" to a channel to signal their interest in receiving updates for this piece of information or data or content... etc.

Someone else then might come along and update some data, which would otherwise alter their view of the content. Now, the easiest way for the first user to be made aware of this change is by "pushing" the change through their active web socket.

The way I handle this is by wrapping by Models in an Event Listener. When I persist a model back through the persistance layer of my application, (which will 99% of cases be the database), I can have my event listener trigger an event/packet along the respective websocket connection channel that concerns this Model.

You could either send the full snapshot through the channel, or you could just say "hey there are updates available", and the user would then make the actual changes to the server.

The benefit of doing the "push" approach, through setting up event listeners that observe changes to your model is that it scales nicely and you aren't going to have hundreds/thousands of clients constantly refresh.

Comment: Wow, way over my head. Im a simple php developer, not very well versed in javascript.

Comment: In which case, short polling is your friend. There is no way of doing what you need, without polling the server regularly.